# How to execute action, in React Native, when notification arrives and the app is in background without the interaction of the user?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification

I have a React Native app that receives a push notification from my server.
When the app is in background and the user open the notification the app prints a label.
When the app is in foreground and receives the notification the app immediately prints a label.

I would like to print the label without the interaction of the user when the app is in background.

How can I achieve this?

I was thinking to use [Expo Background Fetch](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/) but I need to print the label immediately after the notification and with the Expo Background Fetch I could print too late.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to print labels from Java using this class which overrides the expo notification service

```
public class FirebaseMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    
    //SHOW EXPO NOTIFICATION
    createNotificationsHelper().notificationReceived(createNotification(remoteMessage));
    
    
    //PRINT LABEL IN JAVA...
    
}

public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // put your logic here to update fcm registration token
}

protected NotificationsHelper createNotificationsHelper() {
  return new NotificationsHelper(this, NotificationsScoper.create(this).createReconstructor());
}

protected Notification createNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  String identifier = remoteMessage.getMessageId();
  if (identifier == null) {
    identifier = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
  JSONObject payload = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
  NotificationContent content = new JSONNotificationContentBuilder(this).setPayload(payload).build();
  NotificationRequest request = createNotificationRequest(identifier, content, new FirebaseNotificationTrigger(remoteMessage));
  return new Notification(request, new Date(remoteMessage.getSentTime()));
}

protected NotificationRequest createNotificationRequest(String identifier, NotificationContent content, FirebaseNotificationTrigger notificationTrigger) {
  return new NotificationRequest(identifier, content, notificationTrigger);
}
```

}

and add this in your manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".FirebaseMessageService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="-1">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

Comment: Jorge I need to do it for iOS and Android but with JavaScript code in React Native.